# Encode string column as several dummy columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I'd like to take data of the form

```
     names   label
1    A/B     V
2    A       W
3    A/C/D   X
4    B/C     Y
5    B/D     Z
```

and encode the 'names' column into several columns containing a dummy variable which shows whether a particular name is included, i.e.

```
     A   B   C   D   label
1    1   1   0   0   V
2    1   0   0   0   W
3    1   0   1   1   X
4    0   1   1   0   Y
5    0   1   0   1   Z
```

It feels like there should be an R function which takes care of this easily, but I have not been able to find one. Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to split the string column by `/` and use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(mtabulate(strsplit(df1$names, "/")), df1['label'])
#   A B C D label
#1 1 1 0 0     V
#2 1 0 0 0     W
#3 1 0 1 1     X
#4 0 1 1 0     Y
#5 0 1 0 1     Z
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$names, "/"), df1$label))[2:1])
```

NO packages used

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(names = c("A/B", "A", "A/C/D", "B/C", "B/D"), 
label = c("V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `separate_rows` to put it in long form and then `table` will produce the output. Transpose to get it in the orientation shown in the quesiton.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
  separate_rows(names) %>%
  table %>%
  t
```

giving:

```
     names
label A B C D
    V 1 1 0 0
    W 1 0 0 0
    X 1 0 1 1
    Y 0 1 1 0
    Z 0 1 0 1
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "names   label
1    A/B     V
2    A       W
3    A/C/D   X
4    B/C     Y
5    B/D     Z"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```